# entity relationship for artist album tracks

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

We have 3 tables:
1. Artist
2. Album
3. Tracks

Artist have one or more albums.
Artist can have mores tracks.
Each album have many tracks.

Now, what if a song doesn't belong to any album and It is a single song from an artist. So how to do the entry? and what should we do with the FOREIGN KEY album_id in Track table. Can it be null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 tables which represent entity relations. These will associate your entity sets with their attributes. The relationships between your entity sets aren't clearly defined. Each `Artist` can have many `Albums`, but how many `Artists` can each `Album` have? Each `Artist` can have many `Tracks`, but how many `Artists` can each `Track` have? Each `Album` can have many `Tracks`, but how many `Albums` can each `Track` belong to?

In the real world, a song can appear on many albums but each track / appearance of a song might be viewed as a distinct entity. I'm going to assume that a `Track` can have many `Artists`, but that a `Track` belongs to only one `Album`. In addition, I'll assume we don't need to model the association between `Albums` and `Artists` directly, instead we can use the union of the `Artists` associated with the `Tracks` on each album, which can be obtained easily enough via a suitable query.

[image: Track-Album-Artist ERD]

This requires two relationship relations:

```
TrackArtist (TrackID PK/FK, ArtistID PK/FK)
TrackAlbum (TrackID PK/FK, AlbumID FK)
```

The relationship between `Track` and `Album` can be denormalized into the `Track` entity relation/table, as a nullable `AlbumID` column if you want to allow `Tracks` to exist independent of `Albums`.

If you want different cardinalities for the relationships, the result will look somewhat different. If you want to record a relationship between `Albums` and `Artists` directly, things look much different and you may have to think about consistency between `TrackArtist` and `AlbumArtist`.

Comment: Thank you. I think this the answer. But I still don't know to use null on Album_ID or not. Can you please guide me.

Comment: If you have a separate table for the relationship between tracks and albums (TrackAlbum), then you don't need to use nulls. If a certain track doesn't belong to any album, there will be no record for the track in TrackAlbum. However, if instead you add an AlbumID column to the Track table, then it will have to be null for tracks that don't have albums.

Comment: Thank you. But wouldn't it make problem in the future?

Comment: Nulls do cause complexities but you just need to learn to deal with them when working with SQL databases. Either approach we discussed is valid.

Answer (score 1):

When using a star schema (dimension and fact tables), you could have a fact table with a grain of "track". So each row would be one track. If the track doesn't have an album, then the foreign key for album would be set to 0.

The album table would have a row containing the 0 key, with a description of "not available" or a dash ('-') or whatever makes sense for your reporting purposes.

You could have it null, but if you are doing a count of tracks,and are joining to artists, the row wouldn't return depending on how you write the query.

example query:

```
select t.track_id, t.track_name, a.album_id, a.album_name, art.artist_id,art.artist_name 
from FACT_MUSIC_DB F 
JOIN DIM_TRACKS T ON T.TRACK_ID = F.TRACK_ID 
JOIN DIM_ALBUMS A ON A.ALBUM_ID = F.ALBUM_ID 
JOIN DIM_ARTISTS ART ON ART.ARTIST_ID = F.ARTIST_ID
```

[Table setup example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ38Q.png)

Comment: Albums have foreign key (artist), so record 0 which is called not available belongs to which artist?\

Comment: This is if you are building a star schema. A relational table setup would be different. Your dimensions (artist, album, tracks) wouldn't join together, they would all join to a Fact table. From there you can query the relationships.  I added a pic of the table setup to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making a new table ... songs and making the tracks table a link table with foreign keys for albums and songs. Having nulls in a foreign key breaks what a foreign key is designed for.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key for more details.

Comment: It is a good idea but I am just not sure if it is a professional way or not